# Global event handler has no detail if the object that threw the exeception was created in an event handler

Tags: .net, wpf, exception

Problem with global error handling.
Want to get detail that includes the line that threw the exception.
If the class that throws the error was created in the ctor of MainWindow then it reports the class name and line number of the exception.
But is the class that throws the exception was created in an event handler then zero detail - does not even report the name of the class the threw the exception.
How do I get detail from an exception from an object that was initialized by an event handler?

```
namespace GlobalErrorHandler
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("App_DispatcherUnhandledException Error." + e.Exception.Message + " " + e.Exception.InnerException, "Error");
            e.Handled = true;
            //if (MainWindow != null) MainWindow.Close();
        }
        public App()
        {
            this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="GlobalErrorHandler.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Class1 from Main" Click="Button_Click_Class" 
                Height="20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace GlobalErrorHandler
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Class1 MyClass1 = new Class1();    // this gives line detail
            //throw new Exception();             // this gives line detail
        }

        private void Button_Click_Class(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 MyClass1 = new Class1();      // this does NOT give line detail
        }
    }
}

namespace GlobalErrorHandler
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            throw new Exception();  
        }
    }
}
```

This sample is a Class and a Button event.
But same problem with Page or any other event.
Even if the class that throws the exception is created in the Window Loaded event then zero detail.
Looked at e.Exception.GetBaseException() and still no information.
What is frustrating is in debug mode where the Exception is throw I can view the full stack trace in Visual Studio but that stack trace is gone by the time it gets to App_DispatcherUnhandledException.

Tried including PDB files and that did not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace was there I was just not looking in the right place
Depending if the object was created in a handler or not effects if the valuable stack trace is in the outer or inner exception

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((e == null).ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.ToString() " + e.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().InnerException " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().InnerException);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().Source " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().Source.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.StackTrace " + e.Exception.StackTrace.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e.Exception.GetBaseException().StackTrace " + e.Exception.GetBaseException().StackTrace.ToString());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (e.Exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("InnerException");
            sb.AppendLine(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace))
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string line in e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
                    count++;
                    if (count > 3) break;
                }
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine("OuterException");
        sb.AppendLine(e.Exception.Message);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.StackTrace))
        {              
            int count = 0;
            foreach (string line in e.Exception.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
                count++;
                if (count > 3) break;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "App_DispatcherUnhandledException");
        e.Handled = true;
        if (MainWindow != null) MainWindow.Close();
    }
    public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Release mode, many methods are inlined, so the call stack contains less methods than in the Debug mode. This is where your classes and methods disappear to in the exception.

However, if you **include all necessary PDB files**, the stack traces of the exceptions should be retained, including line number information. So, make sure that when you run the application, the PDB file of the assembly which contains Page classes exists and is accessible.

Comment: Including PDB files did not fix the problem.

Comment: Please provide a sample which reproduces the problem then.

Comment: The question as stated reproduces the problem.  "Look for the // this does not provide any detail"

Comment: I've built the sample. I get full stack traces. If I remove PDB files and build in release mode, stack traces are missing some frames. If you just create an empty app and get empty stack traces, then something is horribly wrong with your environment, but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I believe you but I have reproduced this on two machines.  When you click the button you get full detail?  What can be different about my environment?

Comment: I suggest giving a zip of a complete solution.